# How to make Promise.all of multiple parallel child promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array, and for each element of it, I make an asynchronous call that returns a `Promise`. On fulfillment, those `Promise`s make multiple independent requests that also result in `Promise`s. I want to make a `Promise.all()` super `Promise` that waits for all of the child `Promise`s. I already have code that makes a `Promise.all()` array for the initial `Promise`s.

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Ivan, could you post your current code?

Comment: probably need Array#map and perhaps a Array#concat

Comment: @dhilt - I said "probably", because, as with many things in javascript, there's many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a number of solutions that depend on situation. Following code would work in assumption that all of your low-level requests are executable functions and each execution returns a Promise.

```
const highLevelRequests = [requests1, requests2, ..., requestsN];
const requests1 = [request1_1, request1_2, ..., request1_N];
const requests2 = [request2_1, request2_2, ..., request2_N];
// ...
const requestsN = [requestN_1, requestN_2, ..., requestN_N];

const superPromise = Promise.all(
  highLevelRequests.reduce((acc, request) =>
    [...acc, ...request.map(request => request())]
  , [])
);

superPromise.then(superResult => {
  // process superResult
});
```

At the end we are getting a flat Promise list which is wrapped with `Promise.all`, so we can just call `.then()` on `superPromise`.

---

**Update** in regards of [given code](https://pastebin.com/c1FMMMTE). This is not a flat promise list approach, I just repeated your logic in a more strict manner.

```
var items = [2, 4, 8];
console.log(items + " starting array");
var fn = function (N) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(N * 2), ((Math.floor((Math.random()) * 5) + 1) * 1000)));
};

Promise.all(items.map(fn))
.then(data => {
  console.log(data + " L1 super promise");
  return Promise.all(
    data.reduce((acc, i) => 
      [...acc, ...[1, 2, 3, 4].map(x => fn(x * i))]
    , []));
})
.then((final) => {
  console.log(final + " L2 super promise");
  return final;
})
```

Comment: I've made the following code which is pretty similar, but instead of reducing array I have made Promise.all for each 'highLevelRequests'. It seems to work, but is this the good way? Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/c1FMMMTE

I've also to tried to simply push all high level requests into new array, and  make Promise.all for it inside .then() after Promise.all of low level requests, it worked too.

Comment: @IvanIvanov Your code is too messy, async, arrays... Сложно и непонятно) I refactored it a bit to provide `reduce` and spread concatenation instead of your `for-in`, but I didn't make it super flat due to (as I see) you need a high-level notification. See my updates above.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. You can only call `Promise.all` on an array of promises that you already have. You can however make a promise for each bunch of child promises, by having multiple levels of `Promise.all`:

```
return Promise.all(elements.map(element =>
    doWorkWith(element).then(childResults =>
        Promise.all(childResults.map(doWorkOnChildren))
    )
));
```

The key element here is that the child `Promise.all()` is returned from the parent `.then()` handler (done implicitly here via the fat arrow function), thus it is chained to the higher level promise and therefore that higher level `Promise.all()` isn't resolved until all child promises are also resolved.

You'll get back a promise for an array of arrays of results. Flatten it if you see fit.